# What is the equivalent of Java wildcards in C# generics

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard

I'm developing an application where I the need to invoke a method of a generic class and I don't care about the instances actual type. Something like the following Java code:

```
public class Item<T>{
  private T item;

  public doSomething(){...}
}

...
public void processItems(Item<?>[] items){
 for(Item<?> item : items)
   item.doSomething();
}
```

At the time I was on a hurry, so I solved my problem by defining a interface with the methods I needed to invoke and made the generic class implement it.

```
public interface IItem  
{
   void doSomething();
}

public class Item<T> : IItem {
  private T item;

  public void doSomething(){...}
}

...
public void processItems(IItem[] items)
{
 foreach(IItem item in items)
   item.doSomething();
}
```

This workaround works fine, but I'd like to know what is the correct way to achieve the same behavior.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to refer that the caller of `processItems` doesn't know the actual types. Actually the idea was that the array passed as argument to `processItems` could contain intermixed types. Since its not possible to have such an array in .Net, using a non generic base class or interface seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to make the method generic:

```
public void ProcessItems<T>(Item<T>[] items) {
  foreach(Item<T> item in items)
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Assuming the *caller* knows the type, type inference should mean that they don't have to explicitly specify it. For example:

```
Item<int> items = new Item<int>(); // And then populate...
processor.ProcessItems(items);
```

Having said that, creating a non-generic interface specifying the type-agnostic operations can be useful as well. It will very much depend on your exact use case.

Comment: Blargh, a few seconds too soon. :P

Comment: Yeah, beat me too.  Can you edit with an example of the caller, though?

Comment: Are you writing java here, Jon?

Answer (score 3):

I see that you only want to invoke some method with no parameters... there's already a contract for that: `Action`.

```
public void processItems(IEnumerable<Action> actions)
{
  foreach(Action t in actions)
    t();
}
```

Client:

```
List<Animal> zoo = GetZoo();
List<Action> thingsToDo = new List<Action>();
//
thingsToDo.AddRange(zoo
  .OfType<Elephant>()
  .Select<Elephant, Action>(e => e.Trumpet));
thingsToDo.AddRange(zoo
  .OfType<Lion>()
  .Select<Lion, Action>(l => l.Roar));
thingsToDo.AddRange(zoo
  .OfType<Monkey>()
  .Select<Monkey, Action>(m => m.ThrowPoo));
//
processItems(thingsToDo);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can omit Type Parameters in .NET generic implementation; this is by design. In fact, this can only be achieved in Java because of its type-erasure-based implementation.

You can only use a base non-generic interface (think `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Jon's post. making the method generic (a template) negates the requirement for this sort of functionality (using <?>). You can always feed a type into a generic class/function and for cases where you don't know what type you will need you can make the offending method/class generic as well... ultimately the user has to provide a type when calling such a function or using a generic class, for the code to be able to compile... otherwise you will get some compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue when it came to porting stuff from Java where I've had constructs like

```
if (o instanceof Collection<?>) doSoemthing((Collection<?>)o);
```

Fortunately it turns out that a generic ICollection is also a non-generic ICollection and if someone needs to treat the elements in it as pure objects it is still possible:

```
if (o is ICollection) DoSomething((ICollection)o);
```

That way, since we don't care about the actual type of elements in collection all we get here are objects.
A note here: if the collection was holding primitive types (int or byte for example) then autoboxing kicks in which might introduce performance penalty.