# Any generic in C# (See code)

Tags: c#, java, .net, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of java wildcards in C# generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527766/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-wildcards-in-c-generics)

I noticed this bit of code in a java project:

```
public interface IClientFactory<T extends MMOClient<?>>
```

What would be the equivalent of accepting any generic in .NET/C#?

Comment: Probably something like this: `public interface IClientFactory<T,U> where T : MMOClient<U>`

Comment: @Gabe, I agree, or just make an "interface version" of MMOClient so that you could just do, `where T : IMMOClient`

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IClientFactory<T, TClient> where T : MMOClient<TClient>
```

Comment: But in the OP's question, `MMOClient` *itself* takes generic arguments, so your answer wouldn't work.