# From Java to C# - Generic cast to BaseClass

Tags: java, c#, generics

i currently have a problem with generics. i want to transfer existing java code into c#. can anybody tell me, how i can do following in c# ?

For example i have a class named module with a generic parameter which inherits from basicdata. i want to add many of this objects to a handler so that they all can be updated in a single method.

in java i have something like this:

```
public class BasicData
{
}

public abstract class Modul<T extends BasicData> 
{
  T value;

  abstract void update(); // do something with the value
}

public class Handler
{
    LinkedList<Modul<?>> modulCollection = new LinkedList<Data<?>>();

    void add(Modul<?> m)
    {
        this.dataCollection.add(m);
    }

    void update(){
        for(Modul<?> d : this.modulCollection){
              d.update();
        }
    }
}
```

the list should contain various modul-objects, where the value field itself can have various types but they all inherit BasicData.
i searched a while, but i only found exotic solutions. is there no easy way to do the similar thing in c#? i dont want to rewrite my whole design.

at first i thought i could declare the list like this in c#:

```
LinkedList<Modul<BasicData>> collection;

void add(Modul<BasicData> m)
{
     this.dataCollection.add(m);
}
```

and then add the various objects like this:

```
class DataImpl : Modul<int>
{
}

handler.add(new DataImpl());
```

but i found out that you cannot cast this Modul.
is there a solution to do something like that?

thanks in advance,
mick

Comment: Can you please show code that demonstrates "cannot cast this Modul"? Also post C# definitions of `BasicData` and `Modul<T>` as it is not clear what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not have the ? wildcard mechanics as Java has - [What is the equivalent of Java wildcards in C# generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527766/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-wildcards-in-c-sharp-generics), so there is no direct native solution for this problem.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:**

**1.** Use base non-generic class or interface for your `Modul`:

```
 public abstract class ModulBase : BasicData
 {
   abstract void update(); // do something with the value
 }

 public abstract class Modul<T> : ModulBase ...
```

or

```
public interface IUpdateable
{
    void Update();
}

public abstract class Modul<T> : BasicData, IUpdateable...
```

And use it like:

```
public class Handler
{
    LinkedList<IUpdateable> modulCollection = new LinkedList<IUpdateable>();

    void add<T>(Modul<T> m) // It is generic now
    {
        this.dataCollection.add(m);
    }

    void update(){
        foreach (IUpdateable d in this.modulCollection){
              d.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Your `Handler.moduelCollection` is no longer generic with such an approach, but in any case(even in Java) you would not have been able to access different generics in a simple manner without casting - and that is not the best way to handle different datatypes put into one collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the same in C# like below:

```
public abstract class Module<T> where T : BasicData
{

}
```

Comment: +1, as it may be an answer. Also I suspect that the question is not about that part, but rather about translating [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) type ( `LinkedList<Modul<?>>` ) which does not have direct equivalent in C#.

Comment: thanks for the reply but as alexei levenkov already mentioned, the problem is the conversion from Module<T> to Module<BasicData>

Comment: @mick you welcome dude. Why you need this conversion? I mean using the `T` parameter in the definition of your abstract class, you define an a generic abstract class, where the type you will use each time should inherit the class called `BasicData`. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution for you. It kinda uses what others and you said and combines it with something not mention here.

If you have class *Foo*

```
class Foo {
    public virtual void Method1() {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Method2() {
        //Do something
    }
    //class code
}
```

Now, you have a class *Bar* which inherits from *Foo*

```
class Bar : Foo {
    public override void Method1() {
        //Do something
    }

    public new void Method2() {
        //Do something
    }
    //class code
}
```

If you declare a variable of the class *Bar* and try to convert it to *Foo*, it is completely acceptable and you don't loose any data. However, the next time you want to use the extra properties, methods and variables, you will need to convert it back to *Bar*. Though, if common members are an override, they should behave as if they were called by a *Bar* variable, otherwise, if the object is cloned or cast backwards, the common members should behave as if they were called by an *Foo* instance.

For example:

```
Bar myBar = new Bar();
Foo myFoo = myBar; //Now myFoo and myBar refer to the same memory address
Foo myFoo2 = myBar.Clone() as Foo; //myFoo2 and myBar do not refer to the same memory address

//These should do exactly the same thing because Method1 is an override
myBar.Method1();
myFoo.Method1();

//These should not do exactly the same thing unless Method2 was not changed in Bar
myBar.Method2();
myFoo.Method2();

//These should do exactly the same thing because Method1 is an override
myBar.Method1();
myFoo2.Method1();


//These should not do exactly the same thing unless Method2 was not changed in Bar
myBar.Method2();
myFoo2.Method2();

Bar myBarConvertedBack = (Bar)myFoo; //No data lost
```

Now back to the question. Try this:

```
public abstract class Module<T> where T : BasicData {
    protected T value;

    public abstract void Update();

    public virtual T Value {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Handler
{
    LinkedList<Modul<BasicData>> modulCollection = new LinkedList<Data<BasicData>>();

    pulic void Add(Modul<BasicData> m)
    {
        this.modulCollection.add(m);
    }

    public void Update() {
        foreach (Modul<BasicData> d in this.modulCollection)
              d.update();
    }
}
```

Consider this class as possible derived class from *Module*:

```
public class Class1: Module<BasicData> {
    public Class1(BasicData val) {
        base.value = val;
    }

    public override void Update() {
        //Do something here
    }

    public override BasicData Value {
        get {
            return base.value;
        }
        set {
            base.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also see more cases in *stackoverflow* in the *Related* or *Linked* to this question if it is clear. Furthermore, if I'm wrong somewhere correct me