# Creating Type instance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

As in Java if we declare parameterized constructor of a class as:

```
public KeyCountMap(Class<? extends Map> _mapType)
{
   _map = _mapType.newInstance();
}
```

where _map is defined as:

```
private Map<T, MutableInt> _map = new LinkedHashMap<T, MutableInt>();
```

While in C#, we'll use as:
`Type` instead of `Class<? extends Map>`

```
private Dictionary<T, MutableInt> _map = new Dictionary<T, MutableInt>();
```

instead of

```
private Map<T, MutableInt> _map = new LinkedHashMap<T, MutableInt>();
```

**EDIT**
The actual Java constructor considered is:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public KeyCountMap(Class<? extends Map> _mapType) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException 
{
    _map = _mapType.newInstance();
}
```

As there is no method like `newInstance()` in C# and I'm not sure about what `Activator.CreateInstance()` does exactly.

How will we create new instance of object of class `Type` in C# as done while using java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Comment: @Chris Your suggested duplicate question is talking about parameter less constructor whereas here is a parameterized one. So what ?

Comment: @Underbalanced it is related to both `Java` and `C#` as well

Comment: @Taufel This isn't Java related in the since your simply asking about C# Generics and Wildcards [What is the equivalent of Java wildcards in C# generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527766/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-wildcards-in-c-sharp-generics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class KeyCountMap<T> 
{

    private readonly IDictionary<T,MutableInt> _map;

    public KeyCountMap(){

        _map = new Dictionary<T,MutableInt>();
    }
}

public class KeyCountMap<T> where T: IDictionary<T, MutableInt>, new()
    {

        private readonly T _map;

        public KeyCountMap()
        {

            _map = new T();
        }
    }
```

Also remember map in java is an interface IDictionary in c#. Dictionary and Map are not created equal Map[invlaidkey] =null,  Dictionary[invalidkey] = exception

**EDIT**

The second example satisfies the **EDIT** section. However its not quite equivalent in your example you construct an instance from a type this in c# can be achieved by using the Activator.CreateInstance(). However in c# you have no way to constrain (without writing some reflection) the types passed in. Even then this is a runtime constraint not compile time. So I suggest using generics so the most part; unless you have a particular need to instantiate unknown types at runtime which you have not yet expressed.

Comment: @Mark--well, you initialized `_map` here in this answer, what about `(Class<? extends Map> _mapType)` in the question?

Comment: @Mark--how will we accommodate C# `Type` here, is there any use of it ?

Comment: I think so by using `_map = new Dictionary<T, MutableInt>();` we actually creating a new instance. Fine

Comment: Type is T in my example and yes you can simply "new it up" ill update my answer with more examples

Comment: Yeah I also declared my class as `KeyCountMap<T>` but just was the confusion that will your till suggested answer will cover the constructor as given in my **EDIT** in question

Comment: @Mark--what is the basic difference between your 2 suggested example classes? Which one satisfies the **EDIT** section of question? Please also tell what is C# of equivalent of `_map.keyset();` and `_map.entrySet();` ?

Comment: _map.Keys _map.Values http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx